# WebBrowser doesn't fill the page with content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I set a url to `WebBrowser`:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Width="300" Height="300" Source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Mozilla_Firefox_3.5_logo_256.png"/>
```

but the image appears in the corner. How can I set it to zoom and fill the page with content without white spaces? thanks

Comment: Why use webbrowser control to display image? how about [using Image control](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Image-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx) instead?

Comment: content can be anything. not only images.

Comment: Then create your own page in the isolated storage which loads the target inside an iframe. This way you can control the experience yourself instead of letting `WebBrowser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have went through similar situation. The way which worked out for me, includes not only making change on XAML but also one additional step.

Add *IsScriptEnabled* property to WebBroser as

```
IsScriptEnabled="True"
```

Add code in cs file, where you have show web browser as

```
string description = 
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.onload ="
     + " function () {var elem = document.getElementById('content'); "
     + "window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + '');}</script>" 
     +"<div id=\"content\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width," 
     + " initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0\" />"
     +"<img src=\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Mozilla_Firefox_3.5_logo_256.png\" />" 
     + "</div>";
wb.NavigateToString(description);
```

No need of source tag in XAML.